# clould someone help me with this? why doesn't it compile?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

This is a threaded binary search tree. could you help me find out why it doesn't compile?

http://codeworldtechnology.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/insertion-deletion-and-traversal-in-fully-in-threaded-binary-search-tree/

Comment: Show us your errors, that way we can actually help you

Comment: Show the snippets that have the errors too, that's a large chunk of code which folks don't necessarily have the time to look at...

Comment: (a) Post the code, (b) Compile it yourself [which you did], (c) Post the error.

Comment: `typedef enum { thread,link } boolean;` is a warning sign that the code on that page is no good. I wouldn't be surprised to find `typedef enum { kayak, poodle, banana, humptydumpty } integer;` after that.

Comment: @Nawaz (a) should be write code your-own , don't copy ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Errors:**

```
tree.c: In function ‘main’:
tree.c:51: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
tree.c:51: error: too few arguments to function ‘exit’
tree.c: In function ‘preorder’:
tree.c:327: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

I can see `exit();` is wrong correct it  `exit(0);`

at line 327: `if(ptr->right_ptr==link)` Is wrong because `link` is integer defined as:

```
typedef enum { thread,link} boolean;
```

where as `right_ptr;` is pointer:

```
struct node
{
  struct node *left_ptr;
  boolean left;
  int info;
  boolean right;
  struct node *right_ptr;
}*head=NULL
```

I advise that this code is *broken* there is other many bugs, don't use it!

;

Comment: Yup you beat me to it - although it actually did compile first time for me in a blank Visual Studio project which flagged the same error as a warning (the other warnings were about missing return types and the lack of forward declarations etc). Basically this code is garbage.

Comment: well i basically need a c or c++ source code for a threaded binary search tree. i addressed the problem here cuz i couldn't get it to work. any suggestions?

Comment: @TheMathemagician Thank!..yes it code is not useful..

Comment: @user1969713 suggestions is read Binary-Tree and c++ and try to implement your own..n if you get any trouble let us know at SO..:)